How to prove $\text{Sym}^+(H)$ is an abelian group.

Let $H$ be a shape, i.e., a non-empty compact set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Denote by $\text{Sym}(H)$ the set of isometries preserving $H$ and by
$\text{Sym}^+(H)$ the set of positive orientation-preserving
isometries preserving $H$. Prove that $\text{Sym}^+(H)$ is an abelian
group.

If $f\in\text{Sym}(H)$ then $f(H)=H, A_f$ is an orthogonal matrix, i.e $A\in O(2)$.
If $f\in\text{Sym}^+(H)$ then $f(H)=H, A_f=\begin{pmatrix} \cos x & -\sin x\\ \sin x & \cos x\end{pmatrix}$.
To prove $\text{Sym}^+(H)$ is an abelian group, we need to prove it's indeed a group and $fg=gf\quad\forall f,g\in\text{Sym}^+(H)$. But how can I prove this? Could someone show me?

Essentially, such an isometry has to fix the center of mass of $H,$ but that is messy to define for sets with no interior points.

You can restrict tot the case when $H$ is convex, I think. I might be wrong.

Can you not compute $f \circ g = g  \circ f $ ?

First prove that $\text{Sym}^{+}$ is a group. Next, it's a subgroup of $SO(2)$, which is the group of rotations. Do you see why this group (and so its subgroups) are abelian?

@ThomasAndrews Never mind the center of mass, a nonempty bounded set has a circumcenter (the center of the unique closed ball of minimal radius containing it).

@QiaochuYuan Can you show me how to prove $\text{Sym}^+(H)$ is a subgroup of $SO(2)$? I can show $SO(2)$ is abelian

Ah, I see, this is actually the hard step. Since $H$ is compact a symmetry in $\text{Sym}^{+}(H)$ can't be a translation, so every orientation-preserving symmetry consists of a rotation around some point. Then the problem reduces to proving that every element of $\text{Sym}^{+}(H)$ has a common fixed point. As Thomas says this point can be taken to be the center of mass, although that might get tricky to define.

@QiaochuYuan Since isometries preserving $H$ also preserve the vertex sets of $H$, and thus the centroid is preserved. Then for every $f\in\text{Sym}(H)$, we always have $f(O)=O$ with $O$ is the centroid of $H$. Does this help to prove the problem?

Yeah, once you have a fixed point $O$, each symmetry $f$ gives you the linear transformation $x \mapsto f(x + O) - O$ - and this makes an injective homomorphism $\operatorname{Sym}(H) \to O(2)$.

I still don't see why this help to prove $\text{Sym}^+(H)$ is subgroup of $SO(2)$. Could someone write down the complete explanation in the answering section below, so that I can understand better? Thanks very much

It's not literally a subgroup, but it is isomorphic to a subgroup (namely, its image under the above mentioned homomorphism).

@arkeet But I need to prove $\text{Sym}^+(H)$  is abelian, not $\text{Sym}(H)$

Arkeet's injective homomorphism $\operatorname{Sym}(H) \to O(2)$ restricts to $\operatorname{Sym}^+(H) \to SO(2)$, and $SO(2)$ is abelian.
